# How can I install custom fonts using Bower? (not Font Awesome)

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm using Bower, and already installed Font Awesome with it, but now I'm wondering if I can install a **custom font** (to be more specific: Raleway and Montserrat) using Bower. Can I do that?

I did some research but I didn't find any solution! If it is possible, please tell me how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution I found with Bower was the [Google Fonts Bower Proxy](https://google-fonts.azurewebsites.net/) (source on [Github](https://github.com/CardinalNow/google-fonts-bower-proxy)). You will have to first get the query string by going to Google fonts.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css**?family=fontname:size**' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then using Bower:

```
bower install --save https://google-fonts.azurewebsites.net/googleFonts/yourPackageName?family=fontname:size
```

Depending on the requirement, it may be actually easier to simply import the font to your CSS or SASS instead of going for the bower based solution.

There is also a [google fonts bower package](https://libraries.io/bower/google-fonts) which includes all fonts.

Comment: Actually this VERY helpful. Shame that this answer was at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 7):

`Raleway` is included in the bower package [TypoPRO](https://github.com/rse/typopro/).

Install it with

```
bower install --save typopro
```

As you are new to bower, here some further tips:

As the `bower_components` directory is usually excluded from version control, you can copy the files you need to another directory with a grunt task.

Add a `exportsOverride` section to `bower.json`:

```js
{
  (…)
  "dependencies": {
    "typopro": …
  },
  "exportsOverride": {
    "typopro": {
      "fonts": "web/TypoPRO-Raleway/*"
    }
  }
  (…)
}
```

Install grunt

```js
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
$ npm install --save-dev grunt
$ npm install --save-dev grunt-bower-task
```

and create `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var path = require('path');

  grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
      install: {
        options: {
          targetDir: 'vendor',
          cleanTargetDir: true,
          layout: function(type, component, source) {
            return type;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['bower:install']);

};
```

The grunt task `bower:install` will run `bower install` and copy all files from `web/TypoPRO-Raleway` to `vendor/fonts` (`vendor` from `targetDir` in `Gruntfile.js` and `fonts` from `exportsOverride` in `bower.json`).  You can execute the task with

```js
$ grunt bower:install
```

As `bower:install` is registered as a default task, you can also use the short cut:

```js
$ grunt
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do, instead of managing it with bower, is add in google code directly into your CSS or SCSS `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway)` or manually add the font by first downloading the font then adding the relative path into your css.

You can download raleway here http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Raleway, clicking on the down arrow on the top right of the page, unzipping and add the fonts to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `grunt` instead of `bower` to manage your fonts. I found two grunt plugins which download fonts from Google for you.

[grunt-local-googlefont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-local-googlefont) and [grunt-goog-webfont-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-goog-webfont-dl).  You can install them via `npm`.

There are lots of different plugins to download fonts from other sources.  Just search for `font` at [grunt's plugin search](http://gruntjs.com/plugins).